# How to translate “穷则变，变则通，通则久” to English?

Tags: translation

Is there any elegant and succinct way to translate “穷则变，变则通，通则久” to English? I felt the translation could be quite lengthy when I tried to explain every single character. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*穷则变，变则通*

**ABC**

> Impasse is followed by change, and change will lead to a solution.

**Grand Ricci**

> (provr.) Quand on est à bout, on change, dès que l’on a changé, on aboutit : dès qu’un changement s’est amorçé, une solution peut voir le jour. De tout s’avise à qui pain faut; nécessité est mère d’industrie, d’invention.

The last part is quite sums it up in quite a nice succienct way: *necessity is the mother of invention*.

Answer (score 0):

Poverty demands change, change carries development and permanence follows development.

Comment: I don't think translate “穷” into "poverty" is appropriate...

Comment: What about exhaustion?

Comment: I think 穷 means 困境 here.

Comment: English explanation at http://www.ichacha.net/%E7%A9%B7%E5%88%99%E5%8F%98.html （containing most of above）

Answer (score 0):

“穷则变，变则通，通则久” is just the poetic way of saying "变通".

"变通" means be flexible and improvise. Direct translation of each character means; "变" to change, "通" to get through (the problem).

Poetic translation:
When you are poor (穷) in resources, you will need to innovate with changes (变). Once you got through (通) the problem, your changes will last (久).

Answer (score 0):

Change overcomes impasse and leads to solution.